# How to compress with 'best_compression' elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I compress all elasticsearch data (existing one as well as new data) with the "best_compression" option?

I know since 5.00 version I can't put *"index.codec: best_compression"* in the *elasticsearch.yml* file. I've read the log which indicates that it's deccaped and I should use

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true' -d '{"index.codec" : "best_compression"}'
```

But when used I'm given the following error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.codec]] for open indices [[logstash-dns-2018.07.30/xHq6UfgsSD2M1dBZhV3cOg], [logstash-2018.07.27/7U7uUsEORFqXtJtrk4KvDw], [logstash-dns-2018.07.27/Xbx15QXOQ5KJAK7iop_54Q], [logstash-http-2018.07.27/q0Rs65a3TjW4NJfcljUHEw], [logstash-flow-2018.07.30/0Erbh2TcRgmFJLMLr8Ka8w], [logstash-2018.07.30/boOd8BdrQV2QoziKaZ_2lw], [logstash-alert-2018.07.27/o5yqwdNqR5yAcbJ-HCNVHw], [logstash-alert-2018.07.30/pp6ZWKLISECVzUiCDDeydQ], [logstash-tls-2018.07.30/rZi6KfC7RtqOVjUt7CCqDQ], [logstash-ssh-2018.07.27/wKi-p6slSqO0-vbwRqS1ZA], [.kibana/XaFQRcEXTW6jLUCmBijzKQ], [logstash-tls-2018.07.27/hbiXYCzjRumh3ND6up9vNw], [logstash-flow-2018.07.27/XfspJr1TS4y6MnCgAmRq1g], [logstash-fileinfo-2018.07.27/9VWyBHsqRmO4QsnN-gdt_w], [logstash-http-2018.07.30/U9JO9Cp-QQO7gvRNoHt7FQ], [logstash-fileinfo-2018.07.30/nlwHeDOsQ3ii8CLxcgE3Ag]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.codec]] for open indices [[logstash-dns-2018.07.30/xHq6UfgsSD2M1dBZhV3cOg], [logstash-2018.07.27/7U7uUsEORFqXtJtrk4KvDw], [logstash-dns-2018.07.27/Xbx15QXOQ5KJAK7iop_54Q], [logstash-http-2018.07.27/q0Rs65a3TjW4NJfcljUHEw], [logstash-flow-2018.07.30/0Erbh2TcRgmFJLMLr8Ka8w], [logstash-2018.07.30/boOd8BdrQV2QoziKaZ_2lw], [logstash-alert-2018.07.27/o5yqwdNqR5yAcbJ-HCNVHw], [logstash-alert-2018.07.30/pp6ZWKLISECVzUiCDDeydQ], [logstash-tls-2018.07.30/rZi6KfC7RtqOVjUt7CCqDQ], [logstash-ssh-2018.07.27/wKi-p6slSqO0-vbwRqS1ZA], [.kibana/XaFQRcEXTW6jLUCmBijzKQ], [logstash-tls-2018.07.27/hbiXYCzjRumh3ND6up9vNw], [logstash-flow-2018.07.27/XfspJr1TS4y6MnCgAmRq1g], [logstash-fileinfo-2018.07.27/9VWyBHsqRmO4QsnN-gdt_w], [logstash-http-2018.07.30/U9JO9Cp-QQO7gvRNoHt7FQ], [logstash-fileinfo-2018.07.30/nlwHeDOsQ3ii8CLxcgE3Ag]]"},"status":400}

Comment: `Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.codec]] for open indices` Have you tried closing the indices first?

Comment: How can I close all the indexes ?

Comment: `POST _all/_close` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved:

1. Close all indices:

   http://localhost:9200/_all/_close'
2. Apply best_compression to all

   curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings' -d '{"index.codec" : "best_compression"}'
3. Open all indices:

   curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_open'

Comment: can you please share the doc you referred which changes the index.codec on close+open operations. I need to understand it.

Comment: Actually I read it from another blog and searched from there, not really a standalone article. Here's the link: http://tech.marksblogg.com/billion-nyc-taxi-rides-elasticsearch.html  By the way from the (very small) tests I made with my data I got an extra ~5.5% of compression.

Comment: @palashkulshreshtha, please see on index.codec (a static setting) and close+open here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/index-modules.html#index-modules-settings

I know your comment is old. Yet my reply comment may help someone else. It's still actual in Elasticsearch 7/8 (just change the version from 5.0 to let's say 7.17 or current).

Comment: @miguels, don't you need preserve_existing=true anymore?